# UICollectionView current visible cell index

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview

I am using `UICollectionView` first time in my iPad application.
I have set `UICollectionView` such that its size and cell size is same, means only once cell is displayed at a time.

**Problem:**
Now when user scroll `UICollectionView` I need to know which cell is visible I have to update other UI elements on change. I didn't find any delegate method for this. How can I achieve this?

**Code:**

```
[self.mainImageCollection setTag:MAIN_IMAGE_COLLECTION_VIEW];
[self.mainImageCollection registerClass:[InspirationMainImageCollectionCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
[self.mainImageFlowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
[self.mainImageFlowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0f];
[self.mainImageFlowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0f];
self.mainImageFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
[self.mainImageCollection setPagingEnabled:YES];
[self.mainImageCollection setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[self.mainImageCollection setCollectionViewLayout:self.mainImageFlowLayout];
```

**What I have tried:**

As `UICollectionView` conforms to `UIScrollView`, I got when user scroll ends with `UIScrollViewDelegate` method

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

But inside above function how can I get current visible cell index of `UICollectionView` ?

Comment: self.collectionViewFloors.indexPathsForVisibleItems

Answer (score 158, accepted):

The method [collectionView visibleCells] give you all visibleCells array you want. Use it when you want to get

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    for (UICollectionViewCell *cell in [self.mainImageCollection visibleCells]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.mainImageCollection indexPathForCell:cell];
        NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);
    }
}
```

Update to Swift 5:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    for cell in yourCollectionView.visibleCells {
        let indexPath = yourCollectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
        print(indexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on where self.mainImageCollection comes from? Many thanx in advance for your further detail.

Comment: @BenjaminMcFerren it's the collectionview you used.

Comment: The `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method provides scroll view updates whenever any scroll finishes (and is probably a better choice here). As opposed to the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` delegate method which is only called when the scroll view "*grinds to a halt [from a big scroll]*" (see UIScrollView header).

Comment: IIRC, `..DidScroll` gets called many times, even during a short scroll. May or may not be a good thing, depending on what one wants to do.

Comment: Since iOS 10 it's now also possible to use indexPathsForVisibleItems directly :)

Comment: Better to use self.collectionView?.indexPathsForVisibleItems for short. (added with ios 10 sdk)

Comment: Worth noting that both `visibleCells` and `indexPathsForVisibleItems` will return cells that are not actually visible (i.e. that are off-screen). This might just be a bug in iOS 15.2, though.

Answer (score 224):

`indexPathsForVisibleItems` might work for most situations, but sometimes it returns an array with more than one index path and it can be tricky figuring out the one you want. In those situations, you can do something like this:

```
CGRect visibleRect = (CGRect){.origin = self.collectionView.contentOffset, .size = self.collectionView.bounds.size};
CGPoint visiblePoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect), CGRectGetMidY(visibleRect));
NSIndexPath *visibleIndexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:visiblePoint];
```

This works especially well when each item in your collection view takes up the whole screen.

**Swift version**

```
let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: collectionView.contentOffset, size: collectionView.bounds.size)
let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)
let visibleIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint)
```

Comment: I can agree, sometimes indexPathsForVisibleItems returns more cells, even if we think there shouldn't be such case. Your solution works great.

Comment: I was totally on this kind of situation, just one fix that worked for me (but my case was with tableview), I needed to change the CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect), CGRectGetMidY(visibleRect)); for CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect), CGRectGetMinY(visibleRect));

Comment: Excellent, but if the cells have a space between them then `visibleIndexPath` sometimes will be nil, So `if (visibleIndexPath) == nil { let cells = collectionView.visibleCells()
            let visibleIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(cells[0] as! UICollectionViewCell)! as NSIndexPath }`

Comment: The only solution that worked for my full screen size cells. Added Swift version as an answer below.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, I had my cell take up the whole screen. This worked the best. The other solution returned 2 indexPaths. Here's what i did in swift:

    let visibleRect:CGRect = CGRect(origin: self.collectionView!.contentOffset, size: self.collectionView!.bounds.size)
        let visiblePoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect), CGRectGetMidY(visibleRect))
        let visibleIndexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItemAtPoint(visiblePoint)

Comment: this is perfect!

Comment: Stackoverflow needs a function to allow people to vote or flag what the correct answer is. IndexPath for cell doesnt work if you try to get the visible index in cellForRow when a dequeue is happening and there is only one visible(full screen) cell at a time

Comment: how didEndDecelerating different from didEndAnimation. Both are called at the end..

Comment: This code is working as expected for me on collectionView cell 1st section, when scrolling down to the 2nd section, indexPath is coming "nil".

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more. This problem has been driving me nuts and this solution saved the day.

Comment: This is amazing. For some reason the collectionView was returning an array containing indexes for [0,0] and [0,x] for every third index that was in view. The others would have a correct, single indexpath. Bug on Apples end I assume. This point in rect solution worked perfectly.

Comment: The above code inside function `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` worked as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 104):

**Swift 5**:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var visibleRect = CGRect()

    visibleRect.origin = collectionView.contentOffset
    visibleRect.size = collectionView.bounds.size

    let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)

    guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint) else { return } 

    print(indexPath)
}
```

Working Answers Combined In Swift 2.2 :

```
 func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        var visibleRect = CGRect()

        visibleRect.origin = self.collectionView.contentOffset
        visibleRect.size = self.collectionView.bounds.size

        let visiblePoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect), CGRectGetMidY(visibleRect))

        let visibleIndexPath: NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(visiblePoint)

        guard let indexPath = visibleIndexPath else { return } 
        print(indexPath)

    }
```

Comment: Getting indexpath twice, i need to get only once

Answer (score 20):

For completeness sake, this is the method that ended up working for me. It was a combination of @Anthony & @iAn's methods.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
      CGRect visibleRect = (CGRect){.origin = self.collectionView.contentOffset, .size = self.collectionView.bounds.size};
      CGPoint visiblePoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect), CGRectGetMidY(visibleRect));
      NSIndexPath *visibleIndexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:visiblePoint];
      NSLog(@"%@",visibleIndexPath);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

### UICollectionView current visible cell index: Swift 3, 4 and 5+

```
var visibleCurrentCellIndexPath: IndexPath? {
    for cell in self.collectionView.visibleCells {
        let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
        return indexPath
     }
        
     return nil
}
```

As an Extension:

```
extension UICollectionView {
  var visibleCurrentCellIndexPath: IndexPath? {
    for cell in self.visibleCells {
      let indexPath = self.indexPath(for: cell)
      return indexPath
    }
    
    return nil
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
if let indexPath = collectionView.visibleCurrentCellIndexPath { 
   /// do something
}
```

Comment: Best answer. Clean and a few lines.

Comment: Perfect answer.. Thank you

Answer (score 14):

It will probably be best to use UICollectionViewDelegate methods: (Swift 3)

```
// Called before the cell is displayed    
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
}

// Called when the cell is displayed
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: Regarding `didEndDisplaying`, from the docs: **Tells the delegate that the specified cell was removed from the collection view.
Use this method to detect when a cell is removed from a collection view, as opposed to monitoring the view itself to see when it disappears.** So I do not think `didEndDisplaying` is called when the cell is displayed.

Answer (score 11):

Swift 3.0

Simplest solution which will give you indexPath for visible cells..

```
yourCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems
```

will return the array of indexpath.

Just take the first object from array like this.

```
yourCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.first
```

I guess it should work fine with Objective - C as well.

Answer (score 10):

Just want to add for others :
for some reason, I didnt not get the cell that was visible to the user when I was scrolling to *previous* cell in collectionView with pagingEnabled.

So I insert the code inside dispatch_async to give it some "air"
and this works for me.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UICollectionViewCell * visibleCell= [[self.collectionView visibleCells] objectAtIndex:0];


            [visibleCell doSomthing];
        });
}
```

Comment: This really helped! I didn't realized I can use dispatch_async block to make it absolutely flawless! This is the best answer!

Comment: For Swift 4: `DispatchQueue.main.async {` when call initiates from something like `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {`

Comment: Some clarification: this helped me too, and I had the same/similar problem, when scrolling back to uitableviewcell containing a uicollectionview. The refresh call initiated from `willDisplay cell` as mentioned above. I think the problem, somewhere in UIKit, is really the same in my case as this answer.

Answer (score 9):

> For Swift 3.0

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: colView.contentOffset, size: colView.bounds.size)
    let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)
    let indexPath = colView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

converting @Anthony's answer to **Swift 3.0** worked perfectly for me:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    var visibleRect = CGRect()
    visibleRect.origin = yourCollectionView.contentOffset
    visibleRect.size = yourCollectionView.bounds.size
    let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(visibleRect.midX), y: CGFloat(visibleRect.midY))
    let visibleIndexPath: IndexPath? = yourCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint)
    print("Visible cell's index is : \(visibleIndexPath?.row)!")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`: for this

```
//@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

   - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

        for (UICollectionViewCell *cell in [self.collectionView visibleCells]) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
            NSUInteger lastIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length] - 1];
            NSLog(@"visible cell value %d",lastIndex);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this thread, There are so many solutions that work fine if **cell takes full screen** but they use collection view bounds and midpoints of Visible rect However there is a simple solution to this problem

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let visibleCell = self.collImages.visibleCells.first
        print(self.collImages.indexPath(for: visibleCell))
    }
```

by this, you can get indexPath of the visible cell. I have added DispatchQueue because when you swipe faster and if for a brief moment the next cell is shown then without dispactchQueue you'll get indexPath of briefly shown cell not the cell that is being displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is old question but in my case...

```
- (void) scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    _m_offsetIdx = [m_cv indexPathForCell:m_cv.visibleCells.firstObject].row;
}

- (void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    _m_offsetIdx = [m_cv indexPathForCell:m_cv.visibleCells.lastObject].row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also check this snippet

```
let isCellVisible = collectionView.visibleCells.map { collectionView.indexPath(for: $0) }.contains(inspectingIndexPath)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this, it works. (in the example below i have 3 cells for example.)

```
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: self.collectionView.contentOffset, size: self.collectionView.bounds.size)
    let visiblePoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect), CGRectGetMidY(visibleRect))
    let visibleIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(visiblePoint)
    if let v = visibleIndexPath {
        switch v.item {
        case 0: setImageDescription()
            break
        case 1: setImageConditions()
            break
        case 2: setImageResults()
            break
        default: break
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 3 & Swift 4:**

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   var visibleRect = CGRect()

   visibleRect.origin = collectionView.contentOffset
   visibleRect.size = collectionView.bounds.size

   let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)

   guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint) else { return } 

   print(indexPath[1])
}
```

If you want to show actual number than you can add +1