# UICollectionView: current index path for page control

Tags: ios, objective-c, pagination, uicollectionview, uipagecontrol

I'm using a UICollectionView with a flow layout to show a list of cells, I also have a page control to indicate current page, but there seems to be no way to get current index path, I know I can get visible cells:

[UICollectionView current visible cell index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649920/uicollectionview-current-visible-cell-index)

however there can be more than one visible cells, even if each of my cells occupies full width of the screen, if I scroll it to have two halves of two cells, then they are both visible, so is there a way to get only one current visible cell's index?

Thanks

Answer (score 65):

You can get the current index by monitoring contentOffset in scrollViewDidScroll delegate

it will be something like this

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSInteger currentIndex = self.collectionView.contentOffset.x / self.collectionView.frame.size.width;

}
```

Comment: This is good, but I've found putting the same code in `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` provides a smoother effect if you need to update a UI something.

Comment: May I suggest: `NSInteger currentIndex = (NSInteger)(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x / self.collectionView.frame.size.width + 0.5);`? This gives better results when there are half pages or when a page contains partly showing collection view cells.

Comment: Works very good! Especially with @eunoia suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 36):

Get page via NSIndexPath from center of view.

Works even your page not equal to width of UICollectionView.

```swift
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let xPoint = scrollView.contentOffset.x + scrollView.frame.width / 2
    let yPoint = scrollView.frame.height / 2
    let center = CGPoint(x: xPoint, y: yPoint)
    if let ip = collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(center) {
        self.pageControl.currentPage = ip.row
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice approach, I'd add a equality test from `ip.row` to `pageControl.currentPage` before affectation to avoid triggering useless overhead on `UIPageControl` logic

Answer (score 14):

Definitely you need catch the visible item when the scroll movement is stopped. Use next code to do it.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if let indexPath = myCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.first {
        myPageControl.currentPage = indexPath.row
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work if your collection-view is in page-mode and if your cell-width = screen-width (like a fullscreen pageViewController). The resulting indexPath is not always correct.

Comment: @Rikco Have you found a solution for when page-mode is enabled and cell-width = screen-width? Th is is my exact situation

Answer (score 11):

Swift 5.1

The easy way and more safety from nil crash

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView == newsCollectionView {
        if newsPager.currentPage == indexPath.row {
            guard let visible = newsCollectionView.visibleCells.first else { return }
            guard let index = newsCollectionView.indexPath(for: visible)?.row else { return }
            newsPager.currentPage = index
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

1. Place **PageControl** in your view or set by Code.
2. Set **UIScrollViewDelegate**
3. In **Collectionview**-> cellForItemAtIndexPath (Method) add the below
   code for calculate the Number of pages,

   ```
   int pages = floor(ImageCollectionView.contentSize.width/ImageCollectionView.frame.size.width);
   [pageControl setNumberOfPages:pages];
   ```
4. Add the **ScrollView Delegate** method,

   ```
   #pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate for UIPageControl

   - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
   {
       CGFloat pageWidth = ImageCollectionView.frame.size.width;
       float currentPage = ImageCollectionView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;

       if (0.0f != fmodf(currentPage, 1.0f))
       {
           pageControl.currentPage = currentPage + 1;
       }
       else
       {
           pageControl.currentPage = currentPage;
       }
       NSLog(@"finishPage: %ld", (long)pageControl.currentPage);
   }
   ```

Comment: so if there are ten cells in the collection view, this would calculate the number of pages ten times? Surely once would suffice?

Comment: any better place to add this code : 

int pages = floor(ImageCollectionView.contentSize.width/ImageCollectionView.frame.size.width);
[pageControl setNumberOfPages:pages]; 
???

Answer (score 3):

I had similar situation where my flow layout was set for UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal and I was using page control to show the current page.

I achieved it using [custom flow layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/AWorkedExample/AWorkedExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH8-SW7).

/------------------------
Header file (.h) for custom header 
------------------------/

```
/**
* The customViewFlowLayoutDelegate protocol defines methods that let you coordinate with
*location of cell which is centered.
*/

@protocol CustomViewFlowLayoutDelegate <UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

/** Informs delegate about location of centered cell in grid.
*  Delegate should use this location 'indexPath' information to 
*   adjust it's conten associated with this cell. 
*   @param indexpath of cell in collection view which is centered.
*/

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout cellCenteredAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end

@interface customViewFlowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CustomViewFlowLayoutDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

/------------------- Implementation file (.m) for custom header -------------------/

```
@implementation customViewFlowLayout
- (void)prepareLayout {
 [super prepareLayout];
 }

static const CGFloat ACTIVE_DISTANCE = 10.0f; //Distance of given cell from center of visible rect
 static const CGFloat ITEM_SIZE = 40.0f; // Width/Height of cell.

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
    self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 60.0f;
    self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(ITEM_SIZE, ITEM_SIZE);
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
}
    return self;
    }

- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds {
    return YES;
}

- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
   NSArray *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

CGRect visibleRect;
visibleRect.origin = self.collectionView.contentOffset;
visibleRect.size = self.collectionView.bounds.size;

for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attribute in attributes) {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(attribute.frame, rect)) {

        CGFloat distance = CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect) - attribute.center.x;
        // Make sure given cell is center
        if (ABS(distance) < ACTIVE_DISTANCE) {
            [self.delegate collectionView:self.collectionView layout:self cellCenteredAtIndexPath:attribute.indexPath];
        }
    }
}
return attributes;
}
```

Your class containing collection view must conform to protocol 'CustomViewFlowLayoutDelegate' I described earlier in custom layout header file. Like:

```
@interface MyCollectionViewController () <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, CustomViewFlowLayoutDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
....
....
@end
```

There are two ways to hook your custom layout to collection view, either in xib OR in code like say in viewDidLoad:

```
customViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[customViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
flowLayout.delegate = self;
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout;
self.collectionView.pagingEnabled = YES; //Matching your situation probably?
```

Last thing, in MyCollectionViewController implementation file, implement delegate method of 'CustomViewFlowLayoutDelegate'.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout cellCenteredAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
self.pageControl.currentPage = indexPath.row;
```

}

I hope this would be helpful. :)

Answer (score 2):

<sub>**Note** - I have found **andykkt's** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20626954/1603234) useful but since it is in obj-c converted it to swift and also implemented logic in another `UIScrollView` delegate for a smoother effect.</sub>

```
func updatePageNumber() {
    // If not case to `Int` will give an error.
    let currentPage = Int(ceil(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width))
    pageControl.currentPage = currentPage
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // This will be call when you scrolls it manually.
    updatePageNumber()
}

func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // This will be call when you scrolls it programmatically.
    updatePageNumber()
}
```

Comment: This will not give correct answer if paging is enabled

Answer (score 1):

for swift 4.2

```
@IBOutlet weak var mPageControl: UIPageControl!
@IBOutlet weak var mCollectionSlider: UICollectionView!

private var _currentIndex = 0
private var T1:Timer!
private var _indexPath:IndexPath = [0,0]

private func _GenerateNextPage(){
    self._currentIndex = mCollectionSlider.indexPathForItem(at: CGPoint.init(x: CGRect.init(origin: mCollectionSlider.contentOffset, size: mCollectionSlider.bounds.size).midX, y: CGRect.init(origin: mCollectionSlider.contentOffset, size: mCollectionSlider.bounds.size).midY))?.item ?? 0
    self.mPageControl.currentPage = self._currentIndex
}
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    _SetTimer(AutoScrollInterval)
    _GenerateNextPage()
}

@objc private func _AutoScroll(){
    self._indexPath = IndexPath.init(item: self._currentIndex+1, section: 0)
    if !(self._indexPath.item < self.numberOfItems){
        _indexPath = [0,0]
    }
    self.mCollectionSlider.scrollToItem(at: self._indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
private func _SetTimer(_ interval:TimeInterval){
    if T1 == nil{
        T1 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: interval , target:self , selector: #selector(_AutoScroll), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

you can skip the function _SetTimer() , thats for auto scroll

Answer (score 1):

With UICollectionViewDelegate methods

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    pageControl.currentPage = indexPath.row
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if pageControl.currentPage == indexPath.row {
        pageControl.currentPage = collectionView.indexPath(for: collectionView.visibleCells.first!)!.row
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 5.0

---

```
 extension youriewControllerName:UIScrollViewDelegate{
        func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
            let pageWidth = self.collectionView.frame.size.width
            pageControl.currentPage = Int(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = _cvImagesList.frame.size.width;
    float currentPage = _cvImagesList.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;

     _pageControl.currentPage = currentPage + 1;
    NSLog(@"finishPage: %ld", (long)_pageControl.currentPage);
}
```