# Get Item (or index) of UICollectionView when it stops scrolling

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Is there any easy way of getting Item or index of item when `UICollectionView` stops scrolling?

Comment: What do you mean by "getting item index"? Index(es) of visible item(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I found what item is available on center of the page when UICollectionView Stop Scrolling.
 Based on [this Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24396643/2618600) https://stackoverflow.com/a/24396643/2618600

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"Finished scrolling %@",scrollView);

    if ([scrollView isKindOfClass:[UICollectionView class]])
    {

        UICollectionView *mainCollection = (UICollectionView *) scrollView;


  CGRect visibleRect = (CGRect){.origin = mainCollection.contentOffset, .size = mainCollection.bounds.size};
        CGPoint visiblePoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect), CGRectGetMidY(visibleRect));
        NSIndexPath *visibleIndexPath = [mainCollection indexPathForItemAtPoint:visiblePoint];
        NSLog(@"visibleIndexPath %ld",(long)visibleIndexPath.row);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `- (NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleItems` method of `UICollectionView`.