# count which image user is on horizontal collection view, paging enabled

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have an array called imageArray = ["one", "two", ... "eight"]. And it fills a collection view with images. Preconditions: The cell is centered in the view and pretty much takes up the majority of the collectionview/view. The image view is on top and is just a little smaller than the cell. Ok so now I need to count which image the user is on. So if the user scrolls to image 3 I need a way to count 3. I am new to ios programming when it comes to collection views, just found out about them, and need some help. 
Here is some code (basic setup)

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet var mainView: UIView!

var imageArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight"]
     func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageArray.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UserFeedCollectionViewCell
    cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: imageArray[indexPath.row])
    cell.myImage.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0
    cell.myImage.clipsToBounds = true
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Please refer this link.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649920/uicollectionview-current-visible-cell-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

So when you wanted to know which cell is visible on the screen then

1. Use property [visibleCells](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618056-visiblecells?language=objc), it will gives you array of cells which is currently visible on screen.
2. Use property [indexPathsForVisibleItems](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618020-indexpathsforvisibleitems?language=objc), it will gives you array of indexPath of all visible cells.

**For info**

In `UICollectionView` you are using `dequeue` property. The  `dequeue` property works something like this :

let you have N cells and **`V`** cells are possible on the screen then it takes memory of **`V+1`** cell and after scrolling it releases the memory from the early cell and give it to new visible cell.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is this:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var aPoint = CGPoint()
    collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: aPoint)
}
```

once you have the index for, let's say the center of the screen or UICollectionView, you can figure out the row and thus the image.