# How to get current index path of collection view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am new in swift and I am facing problem to get current `indexpath` of collection view
my code is like this

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    for cell in SliderCollectionView.visibleCells {
        let indexPath = SliderCollectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
        print(indexPath)
    }
}
```

I am getting `indexPath` but like this Optional([0, 2])
But I need it as 2

Comment: most correctly with collection its item not row

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UICollectionView current visible cell index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649920/uicollectionview-current-visible-cell-index)

Comment: @Sailendra No I Accepted the answer which help me

Comment: @ Mujtaba your code is correct only you need to get row from indexPath like print(indexPath.row).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `if-let`

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    for cell in SliderCollectionView.visibleCells {
      if let row = SliderCollectionView.indexPath(for: cell)?.item {
           print(row) 
      }
    }
}
```

you can access the visible indices directly

```
 for index in SliderCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems {
    print(index.item)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `indexPath` with `indexPath.row`

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    for cell in SliderCollectionView.visibleCells {
        let indexPath = SliderCollectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
        print(indexPath.row)

    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with this

```
if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) {
   print(indexPath.row)
}
```